# Main Getter for a Javascript class

Tags: javascript, class

So i want to create a class and add a getter to return something when getting the entire instance instead of a getter on one of the children.

example:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name
  }

  get () {
    return "My name is " + this.name;
  }
}

const Alexander = new Person("Alexander")

console.log(Alexander) // My name is Alexander
```

So the above is what i want to achieve, but i am unable to and struggling to find something online like this, unsure if it is possible or my wording is just incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `toString()` function of a class defines what should be printed if the class is converted to a string. You can override that function in the following way:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;

    // override function here
    this.toString = function() {
      return "My name is " + this.name;
    }
  }
}

const Alexander = new Person("Alexander")
console.log("" + Alexander) // My name is Alexander
```

But it will only get printed if the object is converted to a string. For example by adding it to a string as in the example above (e.g. `"" + object`) or by doing `String(object)` or simply `object.toString()`.

Comment: What about `.valueOf()`?